Next.js 14 Supabase Auth: Private Page Access Issue
I followed Supabase's Setting up Server-Side Auth for Next.js guide (https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/server-side/nextjs) to set up a basic Next.js application with a user authentication system.
The Issue:
After successful login, users are redirected to the /private page, accessible only when logged in. However, I encounter an error upon accessing /private post-login.
Error:

I attempted using const export-dynamic = 'force-dynamic' and unstable_noStore() as per Next.js Dynamic Rendering docs, but the error persists. Any guidance on resolving this issue would be appreciated.

Could you edit your question and add what the error says?
